# joomla website: alignment issue

Tags: joomla

### I am working on joomla website everything was going fine when I was suddenly stuck in services section

my site url is http://glow1.byethost12.com/glow/index.php ## when you scroll down to "our services" area
Community outreach and mobilisation and Institutional support doesnot get aligned to the line "Networking and government Liaison". it's a cubic template. initially it was right but later this problem occurs.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you put it in the same module position as monitoring and evaluation. I would check the module position first

Comment: Thank u very much for the prompt response. All the six components are in the same module. these are the feature boxes